# How to configure a MI424WR wireless router to always assign a host the same IP via DHCP?

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

I have a MI424WR wireless router. How can I configure it to always assign the same IP address to a given host on my network, so that the host effectively has a static IP address?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to router via web interface
2. On the top menubar, click on "Advanced"
3. Click on "IP Address Distribution"
4. Click on "Connection List"
5. If the device is already attached, you will need to disconnect it and then click on the remove action (rightmost icon) to delete the existing DHCP reservation
6. Near the bottom of the page, click on "New Static Connection"
7. Enter the Hostname, IP Address, and MAC Address
8. Click "Apply"
9. Connect the device